# An easy way to do one way sync in github for windows

Tags: git, github

I am reading about git and github, and spending too much on trying to figure this out. I don't want to create my own repository and publish it online as 99% of tutorials online explain. I want to be able to grab some projects locally, and view what's going on in them, and be able to "get latest" so I see what's newly done. Is there a way to do that in github for windows?

Comment: Are you taking about one way to automatically update all your git projects you've downloaded? If not, you can just run `git pull` in any directories you want to update, assuming you downloaded with `git clone ...`.

Comment: Yes Ii want one way to automatically update all downloaded files. To stay up to date with the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact there is. Git is an amazing technology that hopefully you will love. To everyone downvoting you, I understand its broad, but everyone has to learn somewhere! This will assume you have git installed and configured for first time use. Reference [these steps](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/#setting-up-git) to set up and authenticate to github.

Anyway, I am going to walk you through how to easily "clone" and "pull" git repos so you can "have the latest" releases. Let's start by going over a few commands that you will need to know to get started.

The first command is `git clone /path/to/repo`; this command will allow you to clone pretty much any repo that is public. 
The second command is `git pull`; which will pull remote changes to your local working repository.

Now let's learn how to use them!
First we want to make a new directory for our repo to reside in. Personally, I like to make one folder that contains all my repos. So something like /path/to/Repos/ and then inside I would have /path/to/Repos/repo1 and /path/to/Repos/repo2 etc..

Next, we want to enter that directory. So we can run from the command line the following:

```
cd /path/to/Repository/
```

Where /path/to/Repository/ is the path to your local folder you want to keep the working copy.

Next, we can start the "cloning" process. Run the following command. (we are going to use this project for an example: https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js.git)

```
git clone https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js.git
```

Now, you will have a local copy of the repository on your computer! All you have to do is replace the link with the repository you would like to clone.

Lastly, we are going to pull new changes. So when a project releases updates, all you need to do is pull down the new changes and you will have the latest working copy. If you make any changes, you might have to `git merge` the files, but if you need to see that I can update the post later. So let's update this repo.

```
git pull <remote>
```

Where remote is the remote repos name. This will allow us to pull changes to the working directory. Just replace  with whatever the remote directories name is.

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. Yes I read a lot about this subject but couldn't find anyone to help. I am wondering why people downvote instead of just helping others. 

I saw that on github there is a pull request. Won't that update the remote repo, which is the repo for the project I am intending to see the latest stuff for? I want to only see the changes I don't want to make a pull request and update the remote repo. I am understanding something wrong here?

Comment: I tried also using github for windows, it shows sync button, is this the same as what you're talking about? I am using both github for windows and the bash command line.

Comment: So when you make a pull, it does not update the remote repo, all it updates is your local repo. So in other words, it pulls the repo changes from the remote repo TO your local repo. Also, if this answer helps you, and is correct, please mark it as so. @Jacky

Comment: Thank you Daniel. But when they say make a pull request to update the remote repo, what does that mean?

Comment: A pull request is basically you asking the owner to pull down their code and propose updates to it. This will allow you to update different projects code. On the other hand, cloning, then pulling will pull the remote changes to your local repo.

Comment: @Jacky if this answered your question, can you please mark it as so?